# why .profile under home directory does not work when log in

Tags: unix, shell, .bash-profile

I am a newbie to UNIX. I am using mac OS X 10.8. I created .profile under home directory. However, it does not work when login. I always have to force it to work using the command `$ . ~/.profile`. Can anyone explain it for me?

Another question, I try to write a Cshell name wld and make it executable. However, I cannot call it just by typing `$ wld`. I have to type `$./wld`. How to make it work normally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

~/.profile is not read by bash, if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login exists. Also remember that ~/.profile is executed by the command interpreter for login shells and ~/.bashrc is executed for non-login shells. You can read more here: http://stefaanlippens.net/bashrc_and_others

Scripts are usually placed in ~/.bashrc and there is this code in ~/.profile:

```
# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Do note that OS X by default runs a login shell for a new Terminal window.

Comment: @Nykakin: thanks I've tried to use ~/.bash_profile. It works. I also want to practice Cshell as I wrote in the second question, how can I run executable file wld just by typing `$ wld` instead of `$ ./wld`

Comment: See here: http://www.washington.edu/computing/unix/searchpath.html